# How to find stationary points of two-variable cubic

Tags: multivariable-calculus, cubics

I need to differentiate this cubic function to get the stationary points: $$f(x,y) = x^3 + ax^2 + bxy^2 + cxy + dx + e,$$
where $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ and $e$ are constants.

How do I do this?

Comment: do you have specific values for a, b, c etc?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include any work you have done on the problem and indicate where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  For instance, do you know how to find stationary points?  What is their relationship to the derivative?  Do you know the derivative of the function?

Comment: Calculate the partial derivatives ${\partial f(x,y) \over \partial x}$ and ${\partial f(x,y) \over \partial y}$ and set them both equal to $0$.

Comment: Ah, partial derivatives is the way to go. Thanks very much for your help. I can attempt this now.

Comment: Your answer was the most helpful molarmass because you showed me where to get started. If, like me, a person didn't know the name of the technique they were looking for then they can't get started. I can now study partial derivatives and from that hope to be able to use this technique on lots of other problems. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: solve the system
$$d+2ax+3x^2+cy+by^2=0$$
$$cx+2bxy=0$$

Comment: Thank you very much for getting me started on the problem.